# dependency-check" must be declared for element type "bean"

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

```
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN"
        "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd">

<beans>
<bean id="engine" class="beans.Engine" dependency-check="none" >
</bean>
<bean id="car" class="beans.Car">
    <property name="carname" value="Audi" />
    <property name="engine" ref="engine"/>
</bean>
```

**my engine class is look like this **

here i avoid to pass properties

```
package beans;

public class Engine {
public Engine()
{
    System.out.println("Engine");
}
private String modelyear;

public void setModelyear(String modelyear) {
    this.modelyear = modelyear;
}
public String getModelyear() {
    return modelyear;
}
```

}

**I getting this exception while i try to set dependency-check**

```
Apr 01, 2018 12:06:22 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@520a3426: startup date [Sun Apr 01 12:06:22 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
Apr 01, 2018 12:06:22 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [resources/spring.xml]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 5 in XML document from class path resource [resources/spring.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 5; columnNumber: 65; Attribute "dependency-check" must be declared for element type "bean".
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:398)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:258)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:128)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:133)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:620)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:521)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:144)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:85)
    at test.Client.main(Client.java:12)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 5; columnNumber: 65; Attribute "dependency-check" must be declared for element type "bean".
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.addDTDDefaultAttrsAndValidate(Unknown Source)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:77)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadDocument(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:428)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
```

Comment: Post the full exception. The DTD actually allows `dependency-check="none"` for the element `bean`.

Comment: i have posted full exception

Comment: Which Spring version do you use? `dependency-check` seems to be [deprecated](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/container/69162-about-spring-beans-2-5-3-0-schemas).

Comment: Spring Framework 4.2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dependency-check` is deprecated ([source](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/upgrade/spring3/html/ch03s03.html)).

Quote:

> The current spring-beans 3.0 XSD favors a more explicit configuration and relies less on the container to provide some configuration "magic".
>
> The following attributes were removed:
>
> - "default-dependency-check" attribute of the  root element
> - "dependency-check" attribute of the  element